# How do I unwrap correctly?

Tags: uv

Blender noob here. Made a very simple vector square with radiused corners in Inkscape,and saved it as a simple SVG.

Imported to Blender 2.77, changed it to a mesh. Scaled it, then extruded it along the Z axis.

Blend file: [image]

Marked a seam, hit unwrap. The resulting shape looks like a twisted towel.
Only the project from view (ortho),remotely works.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: unwrapping]

Comment: It;'s very hard to visualize what you're describing. Can you post an image or blend file? Otherwise the answer you get will only be as good as the question you asked.

Comment: Without an image that represents the problem you are having, any answers given are just guessing. Please consider adding an image, or if you would like, uploading a file that represents the problem to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and editing your question with the resulting link.

Comment: Which option in the UV mapping window did you used (the little panel that appears after you ask for the unwrap) ?

Comment: The image really helps describe the problem, but I can't reproduce it on my own. I think the actual Blend-file would help the most in this case. Can you upload the source file and link it like @Timaroberts said?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your file, and the first thing I did was remove doubles. Select all in *edit mode*, press <kbd>W</kbd>*>remove doubles* (or just press  <kbd>R</kbd>). Second, I recalculated normals with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd> and then I unwrapped with *Smart UV project*. I think that this will be the best way to go for you. This is the result you can expect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This is exactly what I need. What are doubles, and what makes them appear? Besides "removing doubles", is there a way to check for them first?